# Reload a progressive application every time there is a change on the iis server

Tags: angular, iis, angular-pwa

I have a progressive web application that does not use any caching.  I am looking for a way to update the application automatically every time that there is a change on the server. Is there any way to achieve that ?  Thanks.

Comment: I would say websockets, but creating a websocket for each user would be way heavier than implementing basic caching ...

Comment: The real issue is how to make sure that I am always using the latest version. I am wondering if there is something in iis, or angular that can help.

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544077/react-with-typescript-hot-reload-iis-webserver

Comment: Cache busting is the easiest way. If you don't want to use that, simply force reload your application on deployement of a new application, and manually bust the cache.

Comment: You need a service worker for that. https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro

Comment: The service worker seems good but for months to come I'll be working with a server using http. Even though it is a local network, I am not sure I can still use the service worker on http.